# Swift debugger does not show variable values when importing ObjC framework

Tags: xcode, debugging, frameworks, swift2, xcode7-beta2

When I create a new OS X "Game" project with Sprite Kit, and set a breakpoint anywhere I can see the variable values just fine:

[image]

Then I change the code to import my own framework (TilemapKit) which is a pure Objective-C framework:

```
import SpriteKit
import TilemapKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        print("dang!")
    }
}
```

No other changes made. I'm not even using any of the TilemapKit code (yet). When the breakpoint triggers, I see this:

[image]

The entire project stops being debuggable as far as observing variable values goes. This behavior is perfectly consistent. Without the framework import I can debug again.

Since I'm on Xcode 7 beta (7A121l) and OS X 10.11 developer preview I know this could simply be a (temporary) bug.

Command line Tiles are set to use the Xcode 7.0 version btw. I tried enabling modules in the framework target, made sure the deployment target is the same (10.11), disabled symbol stripping. I added a Bridging Header and #imported the TilemapKit framework in it (removing the Swift import in that case would still give me the non-debuggable app, so it doesn't seem to matter how or where I import the framework).

Does anyone have a suggestion on what could cause this behavior and how I might go about fixing it - or at least how I could try to narrow down the issue?

Is the culprit more likely to be connected to the project's vs the framework's build settings? Do I need to enable something in the app project to make it compatible with ObjC frameworks? (I already got -ObjC in the Other Linker flags)

---

**UPDATE:**

I ran `po self` in the debug console and found this notice:

```
<built-in>:3:6: error: module 'TilemapKit' was built in directory '/TilemapKit.framework' but now resides in directory './TilemapKit.framework'
#define __clang_major__ 7
     ^
missing required module 'TilemapKit'
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.
```

How come the framework build directory changed? And why would that matter and how to fix this?

PS: the same framework in a new ObjC app can be debugged just fine.

Comment: Even I am facing same issue with new a set of Frameworks provided by Twitter. Unable to debug anything. Just shows only variable names and nothing other than that. For me it shows this error. `error: module 'Fabric' was built in directory '/Fabric.framework' but now resides in directory './Fabric.framework'`

Comment: Good to know, sounds like a general issue.

Comment: The same issue in XCode7beta3

Comment: Xcode 11.2.1 still happens, honestly Apple. 5 years issue.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I got a message from an Apple developer stating that they've observed this problem, and that it could be fixed by moving the .framework to a subfolder of the project.

Apparently the `module .. was built in directory` error appears only if the .framework is in the same folder as the .xcodeproj aka `$(PROJECT_DIR)`.

However moving the framework to a subfolder didn't fix the issue in my case, but it's still worth a try until this gets fixed in a newer Xcode 7 beta (still occurs in beta 3).

Comment: i've just confirmed this works.  you also need to update Framework Search Paths in Build Settings

Comment: This solution fixed half of the issue in my case. Frameworks for Facebook and Parse were installed at the project level and moving them in a subfolder worked.  But other frameworks like Alamofire and SwiftyJSON, installed with Carthage and then set as "Embedded Binaries" were still triggering the issue. Adding a "/" at the end of the framework search path for Carthage completely fixed the problem. "$(PROJECT_DIR)/Carthage/Build/iOS/"

Comment: Can't upvote this enough. Debugger is back in business.

Answer (score 16):

In my case this was happening because of redundant `import` statements in my project.

My project mixes swift and objc files, so I have import statements in the `bridging_header.h` file.

In my `bridging_header.h` I had `#import blah.h`

In one of the swift files, I was importing a redundant header from a framework
`@import blah // From blah.framework`

I removed the redundant import from the swift file, that seems to have fixed it.

Comment: For me it was necessary to remove the import headers from a bridging header and to add framework imports to the swift files.

Comment: this works great. I've installed openSSL via cocoapods and it broke the debugger. After inspecting the bridging header I noticed that pkcs7.h was already declared elsewhere. after commenting it out it started working again. such a stupid thing and 2 hours gone

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this is happening in Xcode Version 7.0 beta 4 (7A165t).  I had to remove my ObjC framework to get Debugging values to return.  If removing your framework isn't an option, the print method is old-school debugging, but still works.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a while ago. In my case the Prefix.pch was beeing included inside the Bridging-Header.h. This is not a issue per so, but inside my Prefix.pch there was many C includes that make the lldb fail to import the Bridging-Header. 
So I removed the "#import Prefix.pch" from the Bridging-Header and copied just the "#includes" to the obj-c files that I need to use in swift.

Answer (score 0):

1. The Optimization level is not set to None for the Debug configuration.
   Be sure to set it to None for Objective-C apps as shown in Figure 1 and for Swift apps as shown in Figure 2.

[image: Figure 1 & Figure 2]

2. The Build Configuration pop-up menu is set to Release in the scheme editor's Run action settings pane.
   In Xcode, open the scheme editor by choosing Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme…, select the Run action for your app in the scheme actions pane, then set Build Configuration to Debug as seen in Figure 3.

[image: Figure 3]

Answer (score -4):

Go to Edit Scheme on left top corner.

And change the configurations to Debug, if it is release [image: here]

Comment: Like I said, the problem goes away as soon as I comment out the import line. Of course it's a debug build.

Comment: OP showed that he was able to see the variables, which is only possible in Debug. The change he made was include an import.