# error: module 'Fabric' was built in directory '/Fabric.framework' but now resides in directory './Fabric.framework'

Tags: ios, xcode

Since I updated my project to XCode7beta3, there is permanent error when I try to print whatever on console:

> error: module 'Fabric' was built in directory '/Fabric.framework' but now resides in directory './Fabric.framework'

How to fix this issue?

Comment: just check in target->build phases->runscript and check path...i just give a try not sure

Comment: try to move .framework to the subfolder...check here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219422/swift-debugger-does-not-show-variable-values-when-importing-objc-framework

Comment: Ok, I moved it to a subfolder `Frameworks/`. In Frameworks Search Paths in Build Phase I set `$(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)/Frameworks`, but I do not know what to put in Run Script Build Phase. Now I have: `./Fabric.framework/`, but when I run I got an error: `./Fabric.framework/run: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

You should move the Fabric framework to a subfolder (maybe the Crashlytics framework too) and update the run script accordingly:
./Frameworks/Fabric.framework/run .....