# Debug mode not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, debugging, cocoapods

After certain pod installation, my app's debug mode stop working. On breakpoint, when i try to print any value in console by typing

```
po cell
```

it's giving me following error.

```
warning: Swift error in module DemoAppDebug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

error: Error in auto-import:
failed to get module 'DemoApp' from AST context:
/Users/macExpert/IOS Projects/DemoApp/Source/DemoApp/Demo-Bridging-Header.h:12:9: note: in file included from /Users/macExpert/IOS Projects/DemoApp/Source/DemoApp/Demo-Bridging-Header.h:12:
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
    ^
/Users/macExpert/IOS     Projects/DemoApp/Source/DemoApp/DemoApp/ThirdParty/MBProgressHUD/MBProgress    HUD.h:38:2: error: redefinition of enumerator     'MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate'
        MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate,
    ^
/Users/macExpert/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoApp-    amtojfejfgssxoeugwoimotdqqbr/Build/Products/Debug-    iphonesimulator/MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.framework/Headers/MBProgressHUD    .h:38:2: note: previous definition is here
        MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate,
    ^
```

Faced this type of issue first time. Experts please help

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219422/swift-debugger-does-not-show-variable-values-when-importing-objc-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just remove some unwanted **import statements** from **bridging file** and the debug mode start working.