# Module was built in directory but now resides in directory '.' Swift XCode 8

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm adding a static library for my project on link binary with libraries, the .a file is inside my project's directory, also the headers.

I've created the .h headers for it. This is what the compiler throws

[image]

What do I have to do to fix this issue? I
Thanks

Comment: Is [this question/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219422/swift-debugger-does-not-show-variable-values-when-importing-objc-framework) useful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Clean and build once again.I assume you have the reference of the module